# Why does onActivityResult() gets called when the person who is calling it is null?

Tags: java, android

I spend a great deal of time trying to figure out how does the `onActivityResult()` method gets called everytime you use `startActivityForResult()` in an activity and is expecting a result. So I dig around and I was able to locate what method called the `onActivityResult()`.
However, what confused me was the `who` variable has to be null in order for `onActivityResult()` to be called. The `who` variable, I thought, represents the activity that is either returning the result or the activity that is calling for the result. Now if `who = null` then why should onActivityResult() be called since no one is needing a result to be deliver nor is there exist any activity that generate the results. So can anyone explain to me why `who = null`?

Source

```
6185    public void dispatchActivityResult(String who, int requestCode,
6186        int resultCode, Intent data) {
6187        if (false) Log.v(
6188            TAG, "Dispatching result: who=" + who + ", reqCode=" + requestCode
6189            + ", resCode=" + resultCode + ", data=" + data);
6190        mFragments.noteStateNotSaved();
6191        if (who == null) {
6192            onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
6193        } else {
6194            Fragment frag = mFragments.findFragmentByWho(who);
6195            if (frag != null) {
6196                frag.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
6197            }
6198        }
6199    }
```

Prove that who represents the activity that called startActivityForResult().

The method startActivityForResult():

```
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, @Nullable Bundle options) {
3744        if (mParent == null) {
3745            Instrumentation.ActivityResult ar =
3746                mInstrumentation.execStartActivity(
3747                    this, mMainThread.getApplicationThread(), mToken, this,
3748                    intent, requestCode, options);
3749            if (ar != null) {
3750                mMainThread.sendActivityResult(
3751                    mToken, mEmbeddedID, requestCode, ar.getResultCode(),
3752                    ar.getResultData());
3753            }
```

You can see that execStartActivity have this which is the current activity passed into it as a who.

```
            public ActivityResult execStartActivity(
1475            Context who, IBinder contextThread, IBinder token, Activity target,
1476            Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right in the code: If `who` is not null, the result is delivered to a `Fragment` instead of the `Activity`.

Comment: wait I still don't get it though. Why does who have to be null if it represents an activity that is calling for the result to be delivered? If that is the case then everytime an activity called for a result to be delivered, it would go straight to a fragment even though an activity is calling it and that is not good.

Comment: `who` does not represent the activity which created the result. It stands for a fragment which called `startActivityForResult` and thus wants to receive the result.

Comment: Oh so let me get this straight when you called the startActivityForResult() lets say in your onResume() method of an activity it becomes a fragment that is requesting a result? How does that work? Also, I checked the source code there is no other method calling onActivityResult() except for the one I listed above.

Comment: *If* the caller is a fragment, it is set to `who`. If it is not a fragment (and therefore an activity), `who` is `null`.

Comment: who is actually not null because if you go and take a look at the startActivityForResult(), there is this line of code            ` Instrumentation.ActivityResult ar =
3746                mInstrumentation.execStartActivity(
3747                    this, mMainThread.getApplicationThread(), mToken, this,
3748                    intent, requestCode, options);`      The line of code required this which is the current activity and this represents who. Sorry I am not so sure how to layout what is code so excuse me for making it looks bad

Comment: You think `who` in `execStartActivity` is equal to `who` in `dispatchActivityResult`. That is false.

Comment: Can you explain to me why they are not equal? I am assuming that the process going from startActivityForResult() to the dispatchingActivityResult() the who must somewhat be consistent so that the whole process knows who to send the data back to. Therefore, I think who must be consistent. If who is establish as consistent then the who should never be null. Can you give me a reason to convince me otherwise?

Comment: If who is not null for activities the code in dispatch makes no sense. However, the code works and is correct. Therefore, who is null for activities. I don't know where this is set, and really I don't care either.